# Jacobson radical of Polynomial ring

Tags: ring-theory, modules, radicals

**Definition:** Let $M$ be an $R$ module. Then Jacobson radical of $M$ is denoted by $J_R(M)$ and defined as the intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$. If $M$ has no maximal submodule then $J_R(M)=M$.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S=R[x]$ be the Polynomial ring. We know that Jacobson radical of $S$ is $Nil(R)[x]$ when $S$ is taken as $S$ module. i.e. $J_S(S)=Nil(R)[x]$.

My question: **what will be the Jacobson radical of $S$ when $S$ is taken as $R$ module? i.e. $J_R(S)=?$**

Please help me. I will be highly thankful to You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $S\cong\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}R$ as $R$-module.
Moreover the jacobson radical preserves direct sums, hence
$$J_R(S)\cong\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}J_R(R)$$
that's the submodule of polynomials with coefficients in $J_R(R)$.

---

To prove that the Jacobson radical commutes with direct sum of modules, first note that every $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi:M\to N$ maps $J_R(M)$ into $J_R(N)$.
Applying this to the canonical projections $\bigoplus_iM_i\to M_i$ gives $J_R(\bigoplus_iM_i)\subseteq\bigoplus_iJ_R(M_i)$.
Similarly, by considering the canonical inclusions $M_i\to\bigoplus_iM_i$ we get the reverse inclusion $J_R(\bigoplus_iM_i)\supseteq\bigoplus_iJ_R(M_i)$.